# dom4j XML declaration in document

Tags: java, xml, declaration, dom4j

I need to remove XML declaration from dom4j document type

I am creating document by

```
doc = (Document) DocumentHelper.parseText(someXMLstringWithoutXMLDeclaration);
```

String parsed to Document doc by DocumenHelper contains no XML declaration (it comes from XML => XSL => XML transformation)
I think that DocumentHelper is adding declaration to a document body ?

Is there any way to remove XML declaration from the body of

```
doc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where exactly this the declaration is a problem in your code.
I had this once when I wanted to write an xml file without declaration (using dom4j).

So if this is your use case: "omit declaration" is what you're looking for.
http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/org/dom4j/io/OutputFormat.html

Google says this can be set as a property as well, not sure what it does though.

Answer (score 7):

The simpler solution I choose is

```
doc.getRootElement().asXML();
```

Comment: very simple and nice. this helped me!

Answer (score 2):

You need to interact with the root element instead of the document.
For example, using the default, compact OutputFormat mentioned by [PhilW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/767896/philw):

```
Document doc = (Document) DocumentHelper.parseText(someXMLstringWithoutXMLDeclaration);    
final Writer writer = new StringWriter();
new XMLWriter(writer).write(doc.getRootElement());
String out = writer.toString();
```